# Can "Metal Golem" use metal armor?

Tags: savage-worlds

I'm telling an Accursed Story. One player created a Golem character and chose to be the Metal material.
During the adventure he gained a metal armor.
Can he wear it? Does it make sense for a Metal Golem to wear Metal Armor?

OBS: English is not my primary language, so if it gets a little confusing I'll try to explain it better! :)

Comment: @Szega given how much settings can and do change/add to the core Savage Worlds rules I would seriously caution attempting to answer this unless you have access to the Accursed setting book yourself.

Comment: @Wibbs That is precisely why I asked that. Would there be some problem with posting a quote of the relevant section? Then I believe I could answer and we would not need someone familiar with Accursed Story.

Comment: It would depend on how much text was needed. Snippets are OK, but Posting the entire section relating to a Race in a setting book would almost certainly go beyond fair usage. An additional concern I have is that there may be additional rules elsewhere in the book relating to equipment, armour, etc that apply but are general and not specific to golems.

Comment: @Szega We do prefer to not have questions posting text to help unfamiliar people answer. If someone is unfamiliar with a question's situation, we prefer they not attempt an answer. That makes it more obvious to actual experts that the question needs an answer still, and makes it easier for readers to understand what answers are most relevant. (In other words: asking the question to quote these unusual rules would make it *less* likely to get good answers!)

Answer (score 4):

### Rules as written, they can wear metal armor

The Witchbreed package for Golems has two parts that are relevant to this:

> **Constructed:** While a Golem’s soul is that of a mortal human, his body is a construct of stone, steel, straw, reclaimed flesh, or some other material. Golems do not suffer from disease or poison. They do not suffer extra damage from called shots, nor do they suffer penalties from Wound Modifiers. In addition, they add +2 when attempting to recover from being Shaken. Golems cannot heal damage like their mortal companions. To heal a Golem, a character must use the Repair skill instead of the Heal skill.

The choice of being constructed from stone, metal, or some other material is purely aesthetic, since all Golems have the same stats regardless of the material chosen. Furthermore, nothing says that armor made of metal, wood, cotton, human flesh, or anything else is in any way affected by the material chosen.

> **Hulking:** Golems are, on average, taller, broader, and stronger than other Accursed or the average mortal. They gain a +2 Toughness modifier thanks to the sheer mass of their constructed bodies, and the reinforcing elements added to them.

Golems do gain +2 Toughness due to the material they are made of. But even so, this is *Toughness* which is different than *Armor* that chainmail or whatever provides. While *Armor* does not stack with other *Armor*, it does provide protection in addition to *Toughness*.

In other words, when someone tries to damage you, their damage must exceed Toughness + Armor (although usually stat blocks write it as something like *Toughness: 8 (2)*, which in this case would mean 2 points of Armor, thus "innate" Toughness is *8-2=6*). Toughness is usually calculated by *½ Vigor+2*, but your Golem adds *+2* on top of that. The can still add *+Armor* on top of that.

To give a concrete example, Humans would have a Toughness of *½ Vigor+2*. Golems get a *+2* on top of that. So if my Golem has a d6 Toughness, his Toughness is *½(6)+2+2 = 7*. If I give him Chainmail (*+2 Armor*), an attacker must deal 9 points of damage or more to harm the Golem (and a statblock would write it as *Toughness: 9 (2)*.

<sub>Using the English version of the original Kickstarter rules.</sub>